# Tomcat configure SSL error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: java, windows, ssl, tomcat8, keytool

I want my app on `tomcat` to be accessed using `https:// url`.

For that I have followed these steps:

1. Generated `keystore`:

   `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore amazon.keystore`
2. Generated certificate request (csr file)

   `keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file certreq.csr -keystore amazon.keystore`
3. Submitted `certreq.csr` file to CA and received four file from CA

AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

DV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt

DV_NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA2.crt

my.domain.com.crt

4. Imported these four certificates in amazon.keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias roo
t -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -keystore amazon.keystore

Enter keystore password:

Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias

Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  yes

Certificate was added to keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias INT
ER1 -file DV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt -keystore amazon.keystore

Enter keystore password:

Certificate was added to keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias INT
ER2 -file DV_NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA2.crt -keystore amazon.keystore

Enter keystore password:

Certificate was added to keystore

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tom
cat -file my.domain.com.crt -keystore amazon.keystore

Enter keystore password:

Certificate was added to keystore

5. Added connector in tomcat server.xml file
6. Restart tomcat.

After that when I tried to access tomcat using htts://my.domain.com:8443 I am getting error in Google Chrome as

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

I have searched the web a lot but none of the given solutin worked for me.
I don't even know the root cause for this error.

Can any one suggest me what could be the possible cause for this error?

I have installed tomcat 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.
(Here in command and url I replaced my domain name with dummy name my.domain.com)

Comment: I don't know why but my connector tag is not showing in the question. So putting it in comment:
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="D:\path_to_keystore\amazon.keystore" keystorePass="keystore_password" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  />

Comment: We have to remove a TAG to at least give an indication os the OS were addressing, (my god)

Comment: Please give some regard to the presentation.

Comment: In particular use 'code' formatting (the {} button) for 'console' input and output, and remove the extra lines and obviousy wrong linebreaks. This will also fix your connector: angle-bracket text in stack posts is interpreted as HTML from a limited subset and anything else ignored, but angle-brackets _in code_ are just displayed. You somehow messed up step 4; when you imported my.domain.crt to -alias tomcat if it had worked correctly it would have said `Certificate reply was installed` NOT `Certificate was added`. But it's not clear _exactly_ what you typed. ...

Comment: ... Try `keytool -list -keystore amazon.keystore` to see _exactly_ what entries you have (and add to your question by editting). PS @JonGoodwin: OS usually doesn't matter for Java and here almost certainly not.